# C++ api for Elastic search

Tags: c++, api, elasticsearch

From what I understand, [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org) doesn't provide C++ api with it. So, I'm assuming that I should use a library to send/receive http requests for indexing and searching. Any recommendations on the library that would suit elastic search needs?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any networking library should work fine. [Libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is probably the easiest/fastest to get running, since all you really need are simple HTTP requests (Get/Put/Post/Delete)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to get my indexed results back using libcurl's post data and it seems to have some issues. More information here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272414/elastic-search-json-range-query-issue-when-using-libcurl

Answer (score 10):

I just released one on github: https://github.com/QHedgeTech/cpp-elasticsearch.

There is one home made http client included but it can easily be plugged to libcurl. It's still minimal, hope to see you contribute so it'll match your needs too.

cpp-elasticsearch is a small C++ API to elasticsearch, it aims at becomming the official one.
Documentation is still to come, as well as a "get started" page.

Actual version is minimal and has been developped for the needs of Q-Hedge Technologies.
Features of C++11 are used in this code.

Comment: I see there is no contribution on this repository. Not sure if they have updated the client to latest ES versions. Do you know of any other recommended client?