# Elastic search json range query issue when using libcurl/curl

Tags: curl, libcurl, elasticsearch

I am using libcurl to retrieve my indexed results from elastic search. I have problems with the following code. Meaning, it doesn't return any results. http://pastebin.com/NgdTBTAb

I tried its curl variation (below) with no success.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9202/_all/_search?pretty=true -d '{
    "size": 1000000,
    "query" : {
        "range" : {
            "snapshotTime" : {
                "from" : "2012-10-31T13:00:00",
                "to" : "2012-10-31T14:00:00"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

The same code with out "to" in the range query seems to work fine. Its curl version of the request retrieves all the results. http://pastebin.com/DYi10upZ

Is there something wrong with the way I am querying?

The expected result set (partial) is here. http://pastebin.com/xNLwZmqK

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post also a sample of one of your doc that ES should hit? BTW, I don't think it's a nice idea to ask for 1 000 000 docs.
If you need to extract documents, consider using [Scroll API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/scroll.html).

Comment: I see. I will take a look into the scan and scroll API's. Let me update the question.

Comment: Not sure, but a couple thoughts:  [verify that your mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-get-mapping.html) has the field "snapshotTime" stored and analyzed as a date/time, and that you are using the correct datetime format.  Second, make sure you are querying as a GET request by forcing curl with CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.  I'm not sure if either of these are the problem but it can rule out some low-hanging fruit